Prevent text in UITextView from bleeding outside of textView
I have a UItextView within a UIViewController created in storyboard. The UITextView has an outlet property myTextView and constraints that keep it at a fixed size. One wrinkle: The vertical constraints are initially inactive and set to active if the length of the text exceeds a certain amount.
I can set the text without issue, however, when the text is long it bleeds outside the UITextView at the top and bottom. It doesn't always do this... If the text is just a little bit long, it scrolls okay within the UITextView. However if it is significantly longer than what fits in the textViewwindow a good portion of it (not all) displays outside. It scrolls but bleeds above and below the top and bottom depending on whether you scroll up or down.  I can see the outlines of the textView from a border.
Here is my code:
in .h file
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myViewHeight;

In view didLoad:
[self styleAndAddBorderTo: self.myTextView];
if (descript.length>=32) {
self.myTextView.text = descript;
self.myTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
self.myViewHeight.constant = 240;
self.myViewHeight.active = YES;
}
else {
//display in a UILabel
}

-(UITextView*) styleAndAddBorderTo: (UITextView*) myTextView {
    [myTextView.layer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [myTextView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
    [myTextView.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    [myTextView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [myTextView setClipsToBounds: YES];
    myTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [myTextView.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
    return myTextView;
}

How can I prevent the text from bleeding outside the textView?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
Edit
screenshots

With myViewHeight set to 100 and 320 respectively


Edit
with colors:

comment out setting text
//textView.text = descript;


with textView.hidden = YES;



We need some more information. Using your code, I set the text to 2400 characters and don't get any "bleed." As a side note, the way your code is written, there is no reason to return a UITextField from your styleAndAddBorderTo method.

Unless you mean the actual border line appearing to "bleed"? https://i.sstatic.net/oTl2ZUHA.png

Added pics with height set to 240, 100 and 320 rspectively. The text in the textview always seems to be about four lines too long.  Could it be a timing issue, the border of the textview is set before the text is set and the text is responding to some other layout constraints affected by the amount of text?  There is a textview constraint at the bottom that goes to the next element down--an image that is not being used in this scenario. As of now, I am not touching that constraint. i do set the height of the image to zero elsewhere

That must be happening due to code you are not showing us. Strip down your code (or comment-out sections) until you have a [mre].

It's a storyboard project and I'm think something has gotten messed up in the storyboard. If I create a new simple down storyboard  from scrach I imagine  it will work proerly. But leaving aside autolayout and constraints can you confirm the normal ways to prevent bleeding are [myTextView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[myTextView setClipsToBounds: YES]; and
myTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; ?

Couple notes...
First, this line of your code:
[self styleAndAddBorderTo: self.myTextView];

discards any return value. Since you are passing self.myTextView, let's change your style method to:
- (void) styleAndAddBorderTo: (UITextView*) someTextView {
    [someTextView.layer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    // etc
}

Next, when you set constraints on UI elements in Storyboard, .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is automatically set to false - so you don't need to set that anywhere in your code.
Third, you don't need to set .masksToBounds to true on the text view's layer.
Fourth -- the only two ways I can think of to get your "bleed" problem would be:

somewhere in your code you are setting [self.myTextView setClipsToBounds: NO]; (because the code you've shown explicitly sets it to YES), or
you have somehow overlaid another text view on top of the "styled" one

So, here is your code, implementing the above notes:
@implementation YourViewController

- (void) styleAndAddBorderTo: (UITextView*) someTextView {
    
    [someTextView.layer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [someTextView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
    [someTextView.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    [someTextView.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
    
    // not needed - UI elements (@IBOutlets) with constraints set in Storyboard
    //  automatically set .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE
    //self.myTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
    
    // not needed
    //[someTextView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    
    // we'll keep this here, in case you've set it to NO in Storyboard
    //  or somewhere else in your code
    [someTextView setClipsToBounds: YES];
    
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // let's set the view background to yellow, so we can
    //  easily see the white background of the text view
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellowColor;

    // let's make a really long string
    NSString *descript = @"This is the description string - much, much longer than 32 characters.";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        descript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@", descript, @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."];
    }

    // descript.length should now equal 2,400
    NSLog(@"%ld", descript.length);

    [self styleAndAddBorderTo: self.myTextView];
    
    if (descript.length>=32) {
        self.myTextView.text = descript;
        
        // not needed - UI elements (@IBOutlets) with constraints set in Storyboard
        //  automatically set .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE
        //self.myTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;

        self.myViewHeight.constant = 240;
        
        // this doesn't hurt anything, but is only needed
        //  if you at some point have set
        //      self.myViewHeight.active = NO;
        self.myViewHeight.active = YES;
    }
    else {
        //display in a UILabel
    }

}

@end


Thank you! Setting colors as you suggest it appears there are two instances of the text.  One in thee round green textView looks ok.  Behind it however is another instance.  However the text is set only once with textView.text = descript; and when I comment out the single setting of the text no text appears at all.  When I hide the textview with textView.hidden = YES; both sets of text disappear.  Therefore the second instance of text seems to be in the same textview.

When I scroll the text up and dowm it moves above and below the green so it appears there is only one instance of the text.  It just is not respecting the boundaries or border layer of the text view.

@user6631314 - I have to wonder if you are creating and somehow "layering"  multiple instances of your views? You've got some weird stuff going on with the gray lines below the text view: https://i.sstatic.net/BH4RXn9z.png

@user6631314 - if you're not familiar with it yet, use Debug View Hierarchy so you can inspect the UI at run-time.

Using the visual debugger and clicking on UITextView, something called UITextContainerView is the larger view that bleeds over and the UITextLayoutView is the smaller view respecting the border.

(thanks for pointing out the weird lines. They are created using a UILabel and I forgot to delete the default word Label in the storyboard inspector.)

@user6631314 - UITextContainerView and UITextLayoutView are parts of UITextView. I fear the only way we're going to be able to help is for you to put together a [mre] and share the project.

I have another view controller for posting comments with similar code and constraints that works fine. Something seems to have gone awry in the constraints so I will try to rebuild from scratch. If it still shows problem I will share  as minimum reproducible example. Thank you for all your attention to this.
